# Fastest way to Import Data from AWS Redshift to BI Tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a table in AWS redshift running ra3.xlplus with 2 nodes which has 15 million rows. I am retrieving data on-premise at the office. I am trying to load that data into Memory in a BI tool. It takes a lot of time (12 minutes) to import that data over using a JDBC connection. Also tried on ODBC connection got same result.  I tried to spin up a EC2 with a 25 gigabit connection on AWS, but got the same results.

For comparison loading that data in CSV format takes about 90 seconds.

Are there any solutions as to speed up data transfer.

Comment: You are trying to retrieve 15 million rows from the Cloud to on-premises? It would be a combination of bandwidth limitations, plus the protocol of retrieving that many rows from a database. I presume that your CSV test was from a file stored locally, so the Internet wasn't involved? What bandwidth do you have to the Internet?

Comment: I tried both ways, Cloud to OnPrem and Cloud to EC2 instance. Got about 59 - 70 mbps download on both places. Yes csv on the company network drive, so its on the intranet.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to improve this but the true limiter needs to be identified.  The likely the bottleneck is the network bandwidth between AWS and your on-prem system.  As you are bringing a large amount of data down from the cloud you will want an efficient process for this transport.

JDBC and ODBC are not network efficient as you are seeing.  The first thing that will help in moving the data is compression.  The second is parallel transfer since there is a fair amount of handshaking in TCP protocol and there is more usable bandwidth than one connection can consume.  So how I have done this in the past is to UNLOAD the data compressed to S3, then parallel copy the files from S3 to the local machine piping the files through decompress and saving them.  Lastly these files are loaded into your BI tool.

Clearly setting this up takes some time so you want to be sure that the process will be used enough to justify this effort.  Another way to go is to bring your BI tool closer to Redshift by locating it in an ec2 instance.  The shorter network distance and higher bandwidth should bring down the transfer time significantly. A downside of locating your database in the cloud is that it is in the cloud and not on-prem.

Comment: Thanks for providing the S3 solution. I did create a EC2 instance on the same region on AWS. Installed the BI tool, in this case its Tibco Spotfire and tried importing the data. It took about the same time as on-prem. I Am think if the bottleneck is on the RedShift side? I monitored network speeds on both EC2 and On-Prem was getting about 59 - 70 mbps download.

Comment: I see, the ec2 was connected to RS, not your BI system.  So how long does the query take if the output is sent to a table?  Are we talking about the query taking 12min?  If the query is fast to a table, what about unload to S3?  If things are fast to S3 then the same issues exist  - JDBC not efficient for data, data uncompressed, and single data connection.